# Finding it difficult to extract data from table (JSoup)

Tags: java, jsoup

My code is returning nothing when I'm crawling for elements on the website. I have successfully crawled tables on this website previously. However, I can't seem to extract code from these "dynamic tables" on fantasy.premierleague.com.

**http://i.imgur.com/cHkFwHE.png** < A pic of what i'm trying to extract.

Also, my login details are legitimately shown in the code so you guys can login using my credentials and see for yourself what's going on. (obv it's a spare demo account).

```
public class StatsCollector {

public static void main (String [] args){


    try {

         String url = "https://users.premierleague.com/PremierUser/j_spring_security_check";

            Response res = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .followRedirects(false)
                    .timeout(2_000)
                    .data("j_username", "<fantasyfootball123@guerrillamail.com>")
                    .data("j_password", "<fantasy123>")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();

            Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();


         String url1 = "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/stats/elements/?page=1" ;

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect
                    (url1)
                    .cookies(loginCookies)
                    .get();

            for (Element table: doc.select("table.ismEiwMatchesPast")) {
                for (Element tbody: table.select("tbody.ismHistoryPastSeasons")) {
                    for (Element row: table.select("tr")){
                        Elements tds = row.select("td");
                        if (tds.size()>2){
                            System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + " : " + tds.get(1).text() + " : " + tds.get(2).text());
                            }
                        }
                }
            }



    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StatsCollector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }





}
```

}

Comment: I haven't logged in as you, but it looks to me like those tables are probably generated dynamically via AJAX. You probably should be attempting to extract the data of that AJAX call (usually JSON or XML data), not the HTML that gets generated by the javascript.

Comment: @hisham mohammed before you try to get jtable first try to connect to page.try to `res` to see ,what is the responce .

Answer (score 0):

The content is created dynamically, you can also use [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to "get" to get to the requested piece of data, then you'll be able to parse it (using Jsoup or something else).

Comment: I see. Yeah that's what I thought. I've never used selenium before though. Would you be able to link me to a good tutorial?

Comment: Well, I actually use [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/), which is a groovy browser automation tool. [The book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/) is a great way to start, but you have to be comfortable in groovy (and some jquery).

Comment: Thanks. I think i'll stick with learning selenium for now since Geb seems like it'll take longer for me to get familiar with. (i'm only a novice ).